# how to get FCM message in a UIViewController in Swift3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am using swift3. I want to show `FCM` message to `tableview` in a `UIViewController` when My app receive `FCM` message data.I have got my fcm data using bellow code in `appDelegate`..But I don't know how to get data in `UIViewController`.

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,  willPresent notification: UNNotification, withCompletionHandler   completionHandler: @escaping (_ options:   UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {

    let message : UNNotificationPresentationOptions = .alert

    //GlobalVariables.notification_message = getAlert(notification: .alert)


    if UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active { // In iOS 10 if app is in foreground do nothing.
        print("active****")

        print("\(notification.request.content.userInfo)")
        completionHandler([message, .sound])

    } else {
        print("Not active****")
        completionHandler([message, .badge, .sound])
    }
}
```

Please help me 
Thanks advance

Answer (score 0):

Set a variable on your AppDelegate, then use it from either:

- AppDelegate's didFinishLaunchingWithOptions on `window?.rootViewController`
- Your view controller by calling `(UIApplication.shared.delegate as? AppDelegate)?.yourVariable`

I recommend setting variable in AppDelegate to nil after using it, to prevent using same notification data twice.

Answer (score -1):

In app delegate change your code like this

```
    func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
   // FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.sandbox)
   // FIRInstanceID.instanceID().setAPNSToken(deviceToken, type: FIRInstanceIDAPNSTokenType.prod)

}
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "check")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "userid")
    UserDefaults.standard.removeObject(forKey: "patient_no")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any],fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let state: UIApplicationState = UIApplication.shared.applicationState

    if state == .active{
        UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0

        if let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? [AnyHashable: Any],
            let alert = notification["alert"] as? String {
            print(alert)
            message = alert
            let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertBody = alert
            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
            print("Active----")
        }
    }else if state == .inactive{

        if let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? [AnyHashable: Any],let alert = notification["alert"] as? String {
            print(alert)
            message = alert
            let localNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertBody = alert
            localNotification.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName
            UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
            print("Inactive----")

        }
    }else if state == .background{

        if let notification = userInfo["aps"] as? [AnyHashable: Any],let alert = notification["alert"] as? String,let sound = notification["sound"] as? String{
            print(alert)
            message = alert
            var localNotification = UILocalNotification()
            localNotification.alertBody = alert
            localNotification.soundName = sound
            UIApplication.shared.applicationIconBadgeNumber = number!+1
            print(number!+1)
            UIApplication.shared.scheduleLocalNotification(localNotification)
            print("Background----")

        }
    }
}
```

then add this where you want the message back

```
    let delegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
    let message = delegate.message
```

> - This is a sample only you want to add some condition